# How Hibernate determines type for proxy object

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a abstract `@Entity` with few concrete subclasses. For the sake of simplicity consider:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "classType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Parent {
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("child1")
public class Child1 extends Parent {
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("child2")
public class Child2 extends Parent {
...
}
```

For loading of the class I have a repository which loads the abstract Parent:

```
interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> { ... }
```

When I load the object I get obviously back `Parent` (at the time of loading I get just ID *without* knowing the type):

```
Parent parent = parentRepository.findById(1);
```

But underneath obviously it is the concrete type based on the discriminator value. So I should be allowed to down cast the `parent` above to `Child1` or `Child2`. And this is *usually* the case. But under some circumstances which don't seem to be deterministic I get `ClassCastException` instead:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class ...Parent$HibernateProxy$MZu3Zm6v cannot be cast to class ...Child1 (...Parent$HibernateProxy$MZu3Zm6v and ...Child1 are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

To me it seems that *sometimes* hibernate decides to give me proxy instead of the real class and because the `findById` asks for `Parent` it gives me proxy for `Parent` type even though under the hood there is the real concrete class. So my concrete question based on the above would be:

1. How does hibernate decide that *sometimes* it gives back concrete type (and downcast works as expected) and sometimes I get back `HibernateProxy` for `Parent`? Is it due to the object already being present in `PersistentContext` at the time of loading?
2. How does Hibernate determine the underlying type for the `HibernateProxy`? Why it cannot make it proxy of the concrete type?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, after I've migrated to Hibernate 5.6.x version.

I found two solutions:

1. Use Hibernate.proxy(repo.getId(id))
2. Use findById(id) . This should return the entity, not the proxy.

I'll document this issue here as well: [Spring-boot upgrade, made Hibernate ClassCastException appeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76944140/spring-boot-upgrade-made-hibernate-classcastexception-appeared?noredirect=1#comment135643271_76944140)