# Spring-boot upgrade, made Hibernate ClassCastException appeared

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

As a context the application used spring-boot 2.5.0.
The upgrade from 2.5.0 -> 2.5.15 went smoothly.
But from 2.5.15 -> 2.6.0 , at the runtime the Hibernate ClassCastException was thrown during a cast between the parent class and the child class. This spring-boot upgrade, also as a side effect upgrade Hibernate from 5.4.31.Final to 5.6.15.Final. Based on Hibernate migration guides I didn't see anything that I have to change..

For the sake of simplicity the Hibernate tables look like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "classType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Parent {
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("child1")
public class Child1 extends Parent {
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("child2")
public class Child2 extends Parent {
...
}
```

The error appeared somewhere in a service where the following code is executed:

```
Child1 child1 = (Child1) repo.getById(id);
```

Basically until the upgrade repo.getById(id); returned the Parent entity, that was cast successfully to Child1.
After the upgrade repo.getById(id); returns a proxy, that cannot be cast to Child1.

This is the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class Parent$HibernateProxy$hJgxv3zc
> cannot be cast to class Child1 (Parent$HibernateProxy$hJgxv3zc and
> Child1 are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I see that Hibernate.unproxy(repo.getById(id)) returns the real entity, but why before it worked ? and which configuration I can make in spring-data or Hibernate, to work as it was before the uprade ?

Comment: `Parent` cannot be casted to `Child1`

Comment: Can you add more details ? This application worked like this for years.

Comment: `getById` returns a lazy proxy (it always has btw), depending on what you need/want you should be using `findById` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum this project is working like this for years. Even if I tried with (Chind1) repo.findById(id).get() , I receive the same error.

Comment: The fact that something worked doesn't mean it was the right thing. The `getById` has always done a proxy as it used `EntityManager.getReference` underneath where as `EntityManager.findById` used `EntityManager.find` which are for different purposes. I suspect you were only un-lucky that it worked for the wrong reasons. I also highly doubt that `findById` returns the exact same error.

Comment: Ok, yep that's quite weird that it worked for years in PROD, without any issues. Maybe from Hibernate 5.6.x they did something with proxy mechanism. The only workaround found was to do a Hibernate.unproxy(repo.getById(id)).

Comment: @M.Deinum yes you're right. I did several tests afterwards, and findById(id), works fine. Maybe I can get rid of Hibernate.unproxy(...) . Many thanks. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even until 5.4.x version of Hibernate this worked well, in the 5.6.x this is not working anymore.
So the workarounds are:

1. Use `Hibernate.unproxy(repo.getById(id))`. This will retrieve the directly the entity that can will be cast correctly
2. Use `repo.findById(id)`. Same this will retrieve the entity.